# Return non-optional with .Success enum in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, enums, completionhandler

Question:

How do I define a function in a way that enforces a non-optional type to be passed when an enum that is also being passed in is of type `.Success`? If this can't be done, what's the best way to model this?

Context:

I'm making completion handler based wrapper around our API. The parameters that are passed back to the handler include an `enum` that gives a response status and a `User` instance. The `enum` is something like this:

```
enum ResponseStatus : Int {
    case Success                    = 200
    case InvalidParameters          = 422
    // and a few more
}
```

The method signature is like this:

```
static func createAccount(email: String, password: String, handler: (status: ResponseStatus, user: User?) -> ())
```

The problem with this is that `.Success` could be returned along with `nil` for the user, which shouldn't be able to happen.

I want to be able to enforce that if `.Success` is passed, user cannot be `nil`. Can this be done? If not, what's the best way to manage it?

Thanks in advance for help.

Great answers from both @AlexsanderAkers and @neilkimmett. The only thing that separates them is Alex answered mere moments before Neil. Thanks both!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
enum ResponseStatus<T> {
    case Success(T)
    case InvalidParameters
    // other cases
}
```

Or you could have an `Either`/`Result` type and only use the enum for the error scenarios?

```
static func createAccount(email: String, password: String, handler: (Result<User, ResponseError>) -> Void) { ... }
```

Comment: Did you really mean `Result<User, ResponseError>`? Don't you mean `ResponseStatus<User>`?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a perfect use case for https://github.com/antitypical/Result